# Using Rx in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, system.reactive

I'm trying to use Rx Extensions in a Windows service and I'm stuck. The samples I've found don't work. I'm going to explain with some code what I want to achieve. The very first class I'm creating is actually the class doing all the work:

```
class Worker : IDisposable {
    public Worker() {
    }

    private void Run() {
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }
}
```

I want to create an Instance in OnStart and kill it OnStop:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase {
    private Worker _Worker;

    public MyService () {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    protected override void OnStart ( string[] args ) {
        _Worker = new Worker();
    }

    protected override void OnStop () {
        _Worker.Dispose();
        _Worker = null;
    }
}
```

So I went to doing this in the constructor of Worker:

```
/* _TimesEvents and _Events are class level variables */
_TimedEvents = Observable.Timer ( TimeSpan.FromSeconds ( 1 ), new EventLoopScheduler() ).Timestamp ();
_Events = ( from events in _TimedEvents select events ).Subscribe ( e => Run() );
```

In Dispose, I'm just Disposing _Events. Run is called once. I would suspect it being called every second or not at all.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

To test my `Main()` looks like this:

```
static void Main ( ) {
    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs ();
    if ( null != args && args.Length > 0 ) {
        using ( BRWorker worker = new BRWorker ()  ) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show ( "Press ok to quit", "Test", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK );
        }
    } else {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new BRService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run ( ServicesToRun );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use Observable.**Interval** (http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc14)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Can you please post or link to a sample that shows what goes where in the Service class?

Answer (score 5):

`Observable.Timer` produces a **single** value after the `TimeSpan` is complete. You want to use `Observable.Interval` which produces a new value after **every** `TimeSpan`.